# Вывод двух знаков после точки в случайном числе

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в данном скрипте сделать так, чтобы после точки выводилось только два знака. Например: 3.55 4.12 1.18

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        function showRandomNumber(){
            document.getElementById("myNumber").innerHTML = rando(1, 5, "float");
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        #myNumber{
            font-size:100px;
            text-align:center;
            margin:50px auto;
            font-family:Montserrat, arial;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="showRandomNumber();">
    <div id="myNumber"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Два килобайта скрипта вместо одной строчки с `Math.random()`? По теме: умножить на 100, округлить, поделить на 100.

Comment: собирал весь этот код из готовых решений :( потому что еще разбираюсь

Answer (score 0):

получилось

```js
// Генерируем случайное число от 1 до 5
let randomNumber = (Math.random() * 4) + 1;

// Округляем число до двух знаков после точки
randomNumber = randomNumber.toFixed(2);

// Находим элемент с id "randomNumber" и устанавливаем его текстовое содержимое равным сгенерированному числу
document.getElementById("randomNumber").textContent = randomNumber;
```

```css
#randomNumber {
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-family: Montserrat, arial;
}
```

```html
<div id="randomNumber"></div>
```